# C# / NHibernate have annotation?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In the java JPA, if we need to create an entity mapping to database, we just use annotation, `@entity`, it is almost codeless. In the C#/NHibernate, do we have the similar ?

Thanks

Comment: Heya, it helps when asking a question if you tell us what you've tried/looked for, what research you already did, etc.

Comment: simple and easy way to define an entity. Codeless is the best.

Answer (score 8):

There are [NHibernate mapping attributes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes/), however I don't think anybody really uses it. Currently we have many options to do NHibernate mapping. Besides standard .hbm.xml mappings, there are [FluentNHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/) and, as of NHibernate 3.2, [mapping by code](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-32-mapping-by-code.html).

If you don't want to use .hbm.xml mapping, I would suggest FluentNHibernate or mapping by code. FluentNHibernate is older, has a solid [wiki](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/) for documentation and is generally easier to find examples online.

Mapping by code is newer and it comes with NHibernate (no additional assemblies). You can start looking [here for documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777898/docs-examples-for-nhibernate-3-2-mapping-by-code).

Both NHibernate and mapping by code have concept of auto-mapping using conventions. They will scan over your assemblies in search for entities and map them using default or custom conventions.

Comment: the link is broken. https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/

Comment: Shouldn't be... Maybe you have github blocked? Try going to http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/ and click Wiki link in text.